# How to get selenium to handle crashes or quit from loops after crash

Tags: python, selenium, raspberry-pi

Hi I am currently looking for a solution for my web scraper, It currently has a loop in it that checks for an element and if not there refreshes the page. However the code crashes after several retries, and displays the invalid session ID error or chrome crashed.
I'm trying to run the code from my Raspberry PI 4 using shell and cron, the code also works well in visual studio code.

I would like to know how I can get this to

A. Catch the errors and quit

B. Catch the errors and restart

C. A better solution for my loop

This is my options

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions)
#installs webdriver
driver = webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver', options=options)
```

This is the loop

```
Button = False

while not Button:

    try:

       driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/img')
       print('not clickable')
       time.sleep(5)

    
    except:     

        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main content"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/form/input[2]').click()
        print('clickable')
        
        Button = True
```

Comment: if the browser crashes you may have issues because the chromedriver process will be orphaned. I would avoid using refresh. Instead go to the url. (not sure if that's get() or navigate in python... use get() if available...) This will make sure that the driver waits for the page to load.

Comment: If you can't get rid of the crashes, you'll need to kill the chromedriver process.  You should be able to find that here on SO.  Maybe check the answer posted here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53603901/unable-to-kill-chrome-process-and-running-out-of-memory-with-chromedriver-and-ch